# Adding a data payload to a Xamarin Push notification (GFB and Azure Notification Hub)

Tags: xamarin, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

I've been following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/notification-hubs-backend-service-xamarin-forms) tutorial and have reached the point where I am able to receive push notifications (only working with android for now). My code is almost identical to the tutorial's. I'm now looking to expand the functionality. In the tutorial, when the app receives a `RemoteMessage` object, it parses out the "action" value from the data. It then passes that string to the `NotificationActionService` which triggers an action.

```
    public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
       if (message.Data.TryGetValue("action", out var messageAction))
            NotificationActionService.TriggerAction(messageAction);
    }
```

The downside to this is that the only information it passes to the rest of the program is the name of the action. I want to add additional information. I would usually just add another parameter to the `TriggerAction` method, but the implementation of `INotificationActionService` is pretty involved. I'm wondering if its like that for a reason, or if I can just process my message in the `OnMessageReceived`. What makes me hesitant to change this is that the this action string is also pulled from the `Intent` on start up, and I'm not sure if if this will break it. I'm not entirely sure how android intents work, but both the RemoteMessage and the Intent would require this extra data inside the dictionary.

So, what is the best way to modify this tutorial to allow extra context to be passed in the push notification?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question - and realistically there isn't really one answer. Basically, all Android applications are going to be a collection of Activities and Services. You can think of them like independent threads that the OS is aware of and can help manage. Intents are a standardized way to communicate between these threads using a small set of types that are safe to serialize, so the OS can make stronger guarantees about the how and when it'll be delivered. There's a lot of documentation, and a whole world of different ways to architect your application with these. Each approach will have pros and cons, with some options being way too sophisticated for some applications, and others way too simple.

The Xamarin sample you're referencing keeps two separate threads: one for receiving remote notifications and one for rendering notifications. In principle, a developer may do this to allow notifications to be rendered in response to a message from a remote service OR in response to events local to the phone. For instance, my banking app alerts me that I'm being logged-out after 15 minutes of inactivity, and also when new tax documents are available. The first scenario is best served locally, where a notification will be rendered because a timer reached 15 minutes without being reset. The second scenario is better served by a remote notification so the app doesn't need to poll for new documents.

Bottom line - the sample app may be using an approach that introduces more overhead than your scenario calls for. For others it will be too simple. Choose what is right for your application.

Comment: Thanks. I had a feeling this sample was overkill. I'm not really that concerned about thread safety right now, so I'll do some experiments and report back.